# Returning to the source web page in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm using grail 2.3.3, and am using the webRequest class, within a controller, to obtain action and controller values:

```
    def currentAction = webRequest.actionName
    def currentController = webRequest.controllerName
```

How do I find the 'source' controller & action that invoked this current action? This will enable me to return to that original web page should specific conditions fail in this action resulting in the need to go back. Is there a webRequest value I can use or some alternative way within grails of doing this?

Also it would be useful to know the complete list of parameters that exist
in the webRequest class?

Regards,

Mike

Comment: I thought when you invoke the action from gsp, the params contains thoses informations.

Answer (score 0):

To get the calling web page I have used the command:

```
        callingWebPage = request.getHeader("Referer")
```

There were no references to this in the params class sent over.